# GraphQL Spring AccessDeniedException Handling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, exception, graphql

I am using annotation "@PreAuthorize" for my resolver class and as a consequence I get AccessDeniedException. That's what i want but it is thrown to my log console on server.
I tried lots of things to get off this error and handle it some way just to maybe print one line for example "unauthorized attempt" but not whole stack trace. Do you have any idea where should I handle it?

````
2020-05-16 12:21:27.026  WARN 12308 --- [0.1-1100-exec-1] g.e.SimpleDataFetcherExceptionHandler    : Exception while fetching data (/somePath) : Access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide your own extension of the `AsyncExecutionStrategy` and then construct it with your own `DataFetchingExceptionHandler` like this:

```
@Component
public class QueryExecutionStrategy extends AsyncExecutionStrategy {
    public QueryExecutionStrategy() {
        super(new GraphQLExceptionHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> execute(ExecutionContext executionContext,
                                                      ExecutionStrategyParameters parameters)
            throws NonNullableFieldWasNullException {
        return super.execute(executionContext, parameters);
    }
}
```

While the ExceptionHandler could look something like this:

```
public class GraphQLExceptionHandler implements DataFetcherExceptionHandler {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GraphQLExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult onException(DataFetcherExceptionHandlerParameters handlerParameters) {
        Throwable exception = handlerParameters.getException();
        SourceLocation sourceLocation = handlerParameters.getSourceLocation();
        ExecutionPath path = handlerParameters.getPath();
        if (exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            log.warn("unauthorized to access " +
                        path);
        }
        ExceptionWhileDataFetching error = new ExceptionWhileDataFetching(path, exception, sourceLocation);
        log.warn(error.getMessage(), exception);
        return DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult.newResult().error(error).build();
    }
}
```

You can also then just completely disable any errors reported to the client by returning a `DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult` without any errors attached inside the if statement.

Comment: Now I can see I am kind of handling it, because logs comes from my own DataFetcherExceptionHandler but AsyncExecutionStrategy still produces error with stack trace ` QueryExecutionStrategy.execute(QueryExecutionStrategy.java:22) ~[classes/:na] ` Shall I catch this right there? Or maybe it shouldn't happen there?

Comment: I tried no to attach clause error as you mentioned and it still produces error.

Comment: Ok nvm, I must have done smth wrong before. Now I literally return empty DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult in if statement as u said and it works beautifully. Big Thank you to you :)

Comment: Well it seems that creating ExceptionWhileDataFetching causes error, because when I delete clause .error(error) in return statement it still produces error in server log. Can you explain or link me how does it work?

Comment: We are doing it like this and it works for us: `return DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult.newResult().build();` . We are using a very up to date version of graphql-java and graphql-spring-boot

Comment: I mean that when I am doing `if (exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            log.warn("unauthorized to access " + path);
            return DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult.newResult().build();
        }` then error doesn't show up in server logs but this way I am not passing error to GraphQLErrorHandler and information cant be displayed to client. When I am doing it without return statement inside if block and passing .error(error) as you wrote then I am getting error on server logs I would like to get both -> no error on server logs and display info to client

Comment: Then you probably also need a custom GraphQLErrorHandler and then filter out the DataFetchingException there. You can check if the error is instance of `ExceptionWhileDataFetching` and then also check if the underlying Exception is the `AccessDeniedException` like this: `if (((ExceptionWhileDataFetching) error).getException() instanceof AccessDeniedException)`. I can expand my answer if you have trouble

Comment: I would be very grateful for expanding

Comment: Oh I found my mistake, well that was very stupid... :D I am using lombok to print logs and I was passing `log.warn(error.getMessage(), exception);`. Second argument `exception` was printing whole stack trace :D I am so sorry for taking your time and once again Massive THANK you

Comment: Now I can easily pass to object DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult clause .error(error) and GraphQLErrorHandler gets this error so I can display it to client :)

Comment: Ah yes. Could have spotted that aswell. Glad it is working now!